# Using Blazor Virtualize with Lazy Loading

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly, .net-5

I am doing a straight forward use of Virtualize but have some questions.  I would like to lazy load via making paged calls to the API.  However, we need to know the total count of available Countries.  If I make a call on the OnIntialized to GetCountCountries() and save it as a private variable, then as long as you are on the list scrolling you would never know if a new item was added to countries while on that page.  On the flip side, if I make the call to GetCountriesCount() during the LoadContries lazy load then im getting the most recent count and list.  However, if an item was added Countries but was theoretically in the list that had already been rendered (say alphabetically the country added started with A and the A's had already been rendered on the page) then the get call would technically fetch 1 duplicate entry (the last item fetched in the last page call)

What is the proper way to use the Virtualize?  Should it be used only for UI rendering purposes and GetAll() OnInitialize?  I happen to think that using paging via the API will be most performant from the API and UI perspective.

```
<Virtualize Context="country" ItemsProvider="@LoadCountries">
                    <ItemContent>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@country.Id</td>
                            <td>@country.DisplayValue</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right">
                                <a href="@($"Country/{country.Id}")" class="btn btn-primary table-btn">
                                    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="@($"Country/Edit/{country.Id}")" class="btn btn-primary table-btn">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemContent>
                    <Placeholder>
                        <Loading />
                    </Placeholder>
                </Virtualize>
```

```
private async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<Country>> LoadCountries(ItemsProviderRequest request)
        {
            var numCountries = Math.Min(request.Count, totalCountries - request.StartIndex);
            var countries = await CountryService.GetPagedAsync()(request.StartIndex, numCountries, request.CancellationToken);

            return new ItemsProviderResult<Country>(countries, totalCountries);
        }
```

Comment: `say alphabetically the country added started with A and the A's had already been rendered on the page` Do you implement sorting based on `DisplayValue` in your CountryService GetPagedAsync method?

Comment: That would be the correct place to do it on a paged call.  You have to establish the order before getting the page.  Otherwise i would just fetch 100 out of 10000 items on only order the 100 that came back.